# How to position tables inside column environment?

Tags: beamer, two-column

In my beamer slide, I have a tikzpicture at top. The remaining slide is divided into two columns, each with a table.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\let\familydefault\rmdefault
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,trees,positioning,shapes,calc,fit}

%\usetikzlibrary{dsp,chains}
%\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
%\newcommand{\z}{\mathpzc{z}}

\begin{document}
% Definition of blocks:
\tikzset{%
  block/.style    = {draw, thick, rectangle, minimum height = 1em,
    minimum width = 1em},
  sum/.style      = {draw, circle, node distance = 1cm}, % Adder
  input/.style    = {coordinate}, % Input
  output/.style   = {coordinate}, % Output
}
% Defining string as labels of certain blocks.
\newcommand{\suma}{$+$}
\newcommand{\inte}{$\displaystyle \int$}
\newcommand{\derv}{\huge$\frac{d}{dt}$}
\begin{frame}{\color{blue}{Coordinates+Relative Positioning}}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, node distance=2cm, >=triangle 45,scale=0.7]
\draw

    %node at (02,11)[right=-3mm]{\Large \textopenbullet}
    node at (01,11)[input] (input) {}
    node at (06,11)[sum] (s1) {\suma}
    node at (12,11)[sum] (s2) {\suma}
    node at (14,11)[output] (output) {\suma}


;
\node(B1)  [block,left of=s1,xshift=+.30cm,yshift=-1.50cm]{\Large $D$};
\node(B2)  [block,left of=s2,xshift=+0.30cm,yshift=-1.50cm]{\Large $D$};
\draw[->](input) -- node {}(s1);
\draw[->](B1) -| node[near start]{$\color{blue}{0.5}\color{black}{x_{k-1}}$} (s1);
\draw[->](s1) -- node[near start] {$y_{k}$}(s2);
\draw[->](B2) -| node[near start]{$\color{blue}{0.5}\color{black}{y_{k-1}}$} (s2);
\draw[->](s2) -- node {$z_k$}(output);
\draw[->](input) -- node[near end]{$x_k$}(02,11) |- node[near end]{}(B1);
\draw[->](s1) -- node[near end]{}(08,11) |- node[near end]{}(B2);

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ c | c | c }
$x_{k-1}$ & $x_{k}$ & $y_{k}$ \\
\hline 
\color{white}{-}\color{black}{1} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{1} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{1.5} \\ 
\color{white}{-}\color{black}{1} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{1} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{0.5} \\
\color{black}{-}\color{black}{1} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{1} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{0.5} \\
\color{black}{-}\color{black}{1} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{1} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{1.5} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{table}\flushleft
\begin{tabular}{ c | c | c }
$y_{k-1}$ & $y_{k}$ & $z_{k}$ \\
\hline 
\color{white}{-}\color{black}{1.5} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{1.5} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{2.25} \\ 
\color{white}{-}\color{black}{1.5} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{0.5} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{0.25} \\
\color{black}{-}\color{black}{0.5} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{0.5} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{0.25} \\
\color{black}{-}\color{black}{0.5} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{1.5} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{1.75}\\
\color{white}{-}\color{black}{0.5} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{1.5} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{1.75} \\ 
\color{white}{-}\color{black}{0.5} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{0.5} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{0.25} \\
\color{black}{-}\color{black}{1.5} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{0.5} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{0.25} \\
\color{black}{-}\color{black}{1.5} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{1.5} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{2.25} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I have following issues:

1. I want to align the top of my tables. How can I do this?
2. How can I fix the font size in both columns?

Comment: Unless you want text to flow from one column to another, you don't need columns.  You can simply align the tikzpictures, put them inside minipages, or use a tabular.

Comment: What do you mean by "fix the font size"?

Comment: Offtopic: But instead of "hacking" the alignment of the numbers with the white minus signs, you might want to look into the `siunitx` package, this provides options to align columns for example at the decimal separator. Or simply right align the numbers if they all have the same number of digits. Btw: the minus sign should be a minus sign $-$.

Comment: And please check your previous questions. Many of them have one or multiple answers. If they solved your question, consider accepting them.

Comment: I should have included this in my original post but is it possible to draw these table in tikzpicture environment instead of invoking tabular environment? Should I post it as a separate question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use minipage instead of columns and column environment. use hspace{0.5cm} in between two minipage. After minipage environment command use vspace{-0.1cm} in first minipage and use vspace{0.5cm} in the second minipage and compile your code you will be getting the following.

[image: beamercorrection]

Answer (score 1):

The `columns` has an option for that, `\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\let\familydefault\rmdefault
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,trees,positioning,shapes,calc,fit}

%\usetikzlibrary{dsp,chains}
%\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
%\newcommand{\z}{\mathpzc{z}}

\begin{document}
% Definition of blocks:
\tikzset{%
  block/.style    = {draw, thick, rectangle, minimum height = 1em,
    minimum width = 1em},
  sum/.style      = {draw, circle, node distance = 1cm}, % Adder
  input/.style    = {coordinate}, % Input
  output/.style   = {coordinate}, % Output
}
% Defining string as labels of certain blocks.
\newcommand{\suma}{$+$}
\newcommand{\inte}{$\displaystyle \int$}
\newcommand{\derv}{\huge$\frac{d}{dt}$}
\begin{frame}{\color{blue}{Coordinates+Relative Positioning}}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, node distance=2cm, >=triangle 45,scale=0.7]
\draw

    %node at (02,11)[right=-3mm]{\Large \textopenbullet}
    node at (01,11)[input] (input) {}
    node at (06,11)[sum] (s1) {\suma}
    node at (12,11)[sum] (s2) {\suma}
    node at (14,11)[output] (output) {\suma}


;
\node(B1)  [block,left of=s1,xshift=+.30cm,yshift=-1.50cm]{\Large $D$};
\node(B2)  [block,left of=s2,xshift=+0.30cm,yshift=-1.50cm]{\Large $D$};
\draw[->](input) -- node {}(s1);
\draw[->](B1) -| node[near start]{$\color{blue}{0.5}\color{black}{x_{k-1}}$} (s1);
\draw[->](s1) -- node[near start] {$y_{k}$}(s2);
\draw[->](B2) -| node[near start]{$\color{blue}{0.5}\color{black}{y_{k-1}}$} (s2);
\draw[->](s2) -- node {$z_k$}(output);
\draw[->](input) -- node[near end]{$x_k$}(02,11) |- node[near end]{}(B1);
\draw[->](s1) -- node[near end]{}(08,11) |- node[near end]{}(B2);

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ c | c | c }
$x_{k-1}$ & $x_{k}$ & $y_{k}$ \\
\hline 
\color{white}{-}\color{black}{1} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{1} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{1.5} \\ 
\color{white}{-}\color{black}{1} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{1} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{0.5} \\
\color{black}{-}\color{black}{1} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{1} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{0.5} \\
\color{black}{-}\color{black}{1} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{1} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{1.5} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{table}\flushleft
\begin{tabular}{ c | c | c }
$y_{k-1}$ & $y_{k}$ & $z_{k}$ \\
\hline 
\color{white}{-}\color{black}{1.5} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{1.5} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{2.25} \\ 
\color{white}{-}\color{black}{1.5} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{0.5} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{0.25} \\
\color{black}{-}\color{black}{0.5} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{0.5} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{0.25} \\
\color{black}{-}\color{black}{0.5} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{1.5} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{1.75}\\
\color{white}{-}\color{black}{0.5} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{1.5} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{1.75} \\ 
\color{white}{-}\color{black}{0.5} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{0.5} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{0.25} \\
\color{black}{-}\color{black}{1.5} & \color{white}{-}\color{black}{0.5} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{0.25} \\
\color{black}{-}\color{black}{1.5} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{1.5} & \color{black}{-}\color{black}{2.25} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @samcarter...worked like a charm. Thank you